# Having trouble with a Riddle

Tags: knowledge

You get kidnapped and put into a room. No windows, one door. After leaving the room, I cement it shut. After 2 days I return, blow the door open, go inside, and you're gone... How?

Comment: Are you sure the trivia tag is correct? Do you know the answer to this? (The title suggests not.) If not, where does the puzzle come from?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this puzzle relies on:

> a linguistic ambiguity.

Specifically:

> **After leaving the room**, I cement it shut.

Clarifying things:

> After *you* leave the room, I cement it shut.

So:

> You've left the room, and you aren't in the room.

Comment: Or the room has no ceiling, or it has a trapdoor/tunnel in the ceiling or the floor (neither door nor window).  Or "blowing the door open" kills you, and therefore you are "gone".  Or "gone" means high on something, or mentally not there, because you've gone crazy from being in this room for 2 days.  Or the room you get put in and the one that gets cemented shut are not the same.  Or you're not really gone, just hiding in a secret closet in the wall that's invisible to the naked eye.  Or you're a ghost, or incorporeal, or have teleportation powers, or can shapeshift, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I agree, this is an overly broad question, and I've VTC'd to that effect.

Comment: Building up on @GentlePurpleRain gone assumption, no windows, 1 door, that is cemented shut. The person inside is gone as in dead because the it was an airtight container and he asphyxiated.